# sql - update column by count

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I wrote the following query in `MySQL`:

```
UPDATE mytable atable, 
(SELECT address_one, address_two, COUNT(*) cnt FROM table 
GROUP BY address_one, address_two) btable SET atable.address_count = btable.cnt 
WHERE atable.address_one = btable.address_one AND atable.address_two = btable.address_two
```

it counts how much `address_one` AND `address_two` is listed in the table and stores the number in the respective address_count.

However, this works fine in `MySQL` but not in `SQL Server`. How can I fix this for `SQL Server`?

Comment: Pls provide the specific error message or description of unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
update a
set a.address_count = b.cnt
from mytable a
join (
    select address_one,
        address_two,
        COUNT(*) cnt
    from mytable
    group by address_one,
        address_two
    ) b on a.address_one = b.address_one
    and a.address_two = b.address_two
```

**Side note**: Always use explicit and modern join syntax instead of old comma based join.

Comment: didn't work... it shows: Invalid object name 'atable'.

Comment: @mac - It means the table doesnt exit. To update, you first have to have a tables. What are the names of those tables?

Comment: I only got one table, called 'mytable'. I've just updated it in my code...

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, this is more efficient using window functions:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by address_one, address_two) as cnt
      from mytable t
     )
update toupdate
    set address_count = cnt;
```

In either database, you can use a correlated subquery.  So the following code should work in both:

```
update mytable
    set address_count = (select count(*)
                         from mytable t2
                         where t2.address_one = mytable.address_one and
                               t2.address_two = mytable.address_two
                        );
```